# birt dynamic range parameters

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, range, birt, multivalue

I'm a newbye in Birt and I'd like to develop a report that accepts a "multiple and dynamic range parameter". 
Here you are an example to explain better the problem:

Dataset:
  **table**: Customer
  **columns**: idCustomer, name

I'd like that user will be able to insert multiple range of idCustomer to retrieve names.
Ex: user may want customers for id between 205 and 300 and for id between 501 and 670 and for id between 800 and 920...

I usually do the same thing on BO Crystal Report setting "Allow multivalue" and "Allow range values" to the input parameter. Does exists something similar on Birt ?
I upload an image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvz7F.jpg .It's a BO screenshot for input parameter with "Allow multivalue" and "Allow range values".
Thanks
     GG

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: BIRT doesn't have an option to enable a single parameter to take a range of values.

It does have an option to allow a single parameter to take multiple values, but only for ListBox parameters. Also, you can only bind a single Report Parameter value to a given Dataset Parameter, meaning that you couldn't select on the multiple parameter values within the dataset query (assuming you are using a relational datasource); instead, you would need to add a filter to the dataset, based on the parameter values, in the Filters tab of the Edit Dataset dialog. (And this would still only allow you to specify multiple individual values of the parameter, not multiple ranges of values.)

(Alternatively, you could write a beforeOpen event script for the dataset that would insert the multiple values for the parameter into the dataset's query text directly, instead of binding the report parameters to the dataset parameters; however, this opens your report to the risk of SQL injection attacks. Alternatively, you could add a plugin to BIRT to bind multiple parameter values for you.)

Your options are therefore:

1. Set up a single ListBox parameter, with multiple values enabled, allowing the users to select all individual values they want, and filter the dataset on the basis of the parameter values (or use a beforeOpen event script, or a BIRT plugin).
2. Set up two parameters (for start and end of range) to allow the users to specify a single range of values to be selected, and bind the report parameters to an equivalent pair of dataset parameters in the query.
3. Set up *n* pairs of parameters to allow the users to specify up to *n* ranges of values to be selected (eg. set up 10 parameters to enable the users to specify up to 5 ranges of values), and bind the report parameters to the equivalent dataset parameters in the query.
4. Set up a single textbox parameter to allow the users to enter the ranges freeform (eg. in the format `[205..300],[501..607]`), then write a beforeOpen event script for the dataset to parse the entered parameter value for the required ranges and amend the query text accordingly.

Note that the last option is strongly deprecated because it requires significantly more work, removes the option to specify valid values and opens your report to the risk of [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer. By the way the first one is not good for me 'cause I have many thousand of customers. The 2nd is the easiest way but limit the user. In the 3rd one I'll be able to know how many range the user want and then I'll manage the empty range too. 4th is a good compromise but as you wrote above it's strongly deprecated and introduces SQL injection attacks.